# Sync local Orion with Orionhub?

Tags: eclipse-orion

I have workspaces and users set up on Orionhub. And I installed Orion on my local host. Now is there any way to keep Orionhub and my local Orion in sync?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git repositories for development you could add these as remotes in both orion  accounts.

Then you would stay in sync via git push, fetch, merge/rebase.

Using mozilla persona email address you can also login with the same credetials at each site.